# unable to restore database backup DB2

Tags: database, db2, database-restore, db2-luw

I'm having a DB2 database backup which was done on DB 9 version

> MYDBASE.0.DB2.NODE0000.CATN0000.20120706000435.002

having extension like 002

I'm unable to restore that into DB2 version 10.5

please help me ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should define what "unable to restore" means. For example, if your computer were turned off, you would be unable to restore anything. Is this the case?

Secondly, there was no "DB2 9 version" on LUW. Is it 9.1, 9.5, 9.7, or 9.8 that you are referring to?

Upgrade to DB2 10.5 is possible from DB2 9.7 and up on Linux and Unix, and from 10.1 on Windows.

Another thing to note is that the backup file you've shown appears to be only one of the set of at least two, as indicated by the `.002` extension. I'd expect there to be also the file named `MYDBASE.0.DB2.NODE0000.CATN0000.20120706000435.001`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by mustaccio, there will be one more file which will be ending with `.001`.
Also you can check  test the integrity of a backup image and to determine whether or not the image can be restored by the below command

```
db2ckbkp backup file name
```